# Multiple TTPickerTextField in TTMessageController

Tags: iphone, datasource, three20, message

Is there some way to use multiple instances of TTPickerTextField in one TTMessageController?  I am currently only using the default "To" field with a .datasource, but I am unsure of how to add the others to the main controller.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a Sample app at GitHub under the Samples that shows a way to handle this.

https://github.com/Three20/Samples/tree/master/MultiRecipients